# Xamarin forms breakpoint not hit on android [No compatible code running on the thread]

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I put a breakpoint on an event function on any project, even on a project I just created. I get:
[image: No compatible code running on the thread]

This happens only on Android projects, on Uwp projects, it works great.
I can press the continue button and the code is executed normally and work but I cannot debbug it, see local variables etc...

this is what I get from the output debug:

```
04:27:52:817    Start debugging Android application ...
04:27:52:882    \> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.companyname.app1/crc64ad68f59cd763e462.MainActivity"
04:27:52:882    \> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=\[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER\] cmp=com.companyname.app1/crc64ad68f59cd763e462.MainActivity }
04:27:53:583    Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnvInit.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnvInit.cs:59 \[0x00000\].
04:27:53:768    Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\\a_work\\1\\s\\HotReload\\Source\\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\\HotReloadAgent.cs:423 \[0x00000\].
04:27:53:768    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/System.Core.dll \[External\]
04:27:53:842    Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\\a_work\\1\\s\\HotReload\\Source\\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\\HotReloadAgent.cs:418 \[0x00000\].
04:27:54:209    Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MainPage.xaml.cs:23,1' to void App1.MainPage.ListView_ItemSelected (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) \[0x00000\].
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Unexpected CPU variant for x86: x86_64.
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Known variants: atom, sandybridge, silvermont, kabylake, default
04:27:54:266    \[CompatibilityChangeReporter\] Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10160; state: ENABLED
04:27:54:266    \[ziparchive\] Unable to open '/data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
04:27:54:266    \[ziparchive\] Unable to open '/data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
04:27:54:266    \[nativeloader\] Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.companyname.app1
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Checking if libmonodroid was unpacked to /data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/lib/x86_64/libmonodroid.so
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Native libs extracted to /data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/lib/x86_64, assuming application/android:extractNativeLibs == true
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Setting up for DSO lookup in app data directories
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Added filesystem DSO lookup location: /data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/lib/x86_64
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Using runtime path: /data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/lib/x86_64
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] checking directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] directory does not exist: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/user/0/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
04:27:54:266    \[debug-app-helper\] Mono runtime found at: /data/app/\~\~vxvxmj4IAS5O-va-n9FSyg==/com.companyname.app1-gxyJ-4maXtBZ-u-E90kDvA==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
04:27:54:266    \[monodroid\] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__`
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
04:27:54:266    \[monodroid-debug\] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:51546,embedding=1
04:27:54:266    \[monodroid-gc\] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Symbol file LoadedFromMemory is not a mono symbol file
04:27:54:266    \[libEGL\] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04:27:54:266    \[libEGL\] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04:27:54:266    \[libEGL\] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;-\>computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
04:27:54:266    \[ompanyname.app1\] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;-\>makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
04:27:54:266    \[CompatibilityChangeReporter\] Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10160; state: ENABLED
04:27:54:266    Thread started:  #2
04:27:54:266    Thread started:  #3
04:27:54:266    Thread started:  #4
04:27:54:328    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll \[External\]
04:27:54:328    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll \[External\]
04:27:54:390    \[monodroid-assembly\] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppLinks.dll
04:27:54:390    \[CompatibilityChangeReporter\] Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10160; state: ENABLED
04:27:54:452    Thread started:  #5
04:27:54:452    \[HostConnection\] createUnique: call
04:27:54:452    \[HostConnection\] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x6ffd329587d0, tid 18462
04:27:54:452    \[HostConnection\] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
04:27:54:452    \[OpenGLRenderer\] Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04:27:54:452    \[OpenGLRenderer\] Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
04:27:54:452    \[EGL_emulation\] eglCreateContext: 0x6ffd32959250: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
04:27:54:515    \[EGL_emulation\] eglMakeCurrent: 0x6ffd32959250: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x6fff4e8ed080) (first time)
04:27:54:515    \[Gralloc4\] mapper 4.x is not supported
04:27:54:515    \[HostConnection\] createUnique: call
04:27:54:515    \[HostConnection\] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x6ffd329593d0, tid 18462
04:27:54:515    \[goldfish-address-space\] allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
04:27:54:515    \[goldfish-address-space\] allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f3ffe000 size 0x2000
04:27:54:515    \[Gralloc4\] allocator 4.x is not supported
04:27:54:515    \[HostConnection\] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
04:27:54:577    \[Parcel\] Expecting binder but got null!
```

I'm using Visual studio community 2022 64 bit. Version 17.6.2
I don't think it's relevant but it started to do this since i updated to 17.6.0 (not right the bat but well, i'm giving as much information as I can)

It must be something on my config because It only happens after I click on a ListView item or other (didn't really tried other). When I put a breakpoint on the start of the program, the normal behavior happen.

-I tried to clean the solution, delete bin and obj on every project. rebuild them.
-reinstalling visual studio, all the sdk, my emulator.
-tried on different emulator.
-Using the fast deployment on android
**properties -> android options -> Packaging properties**
-installed Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime 2.7.0.
-Checked filename, directory, etc but even without space or special character, it still happen
-tried on a different computer

Comment: I noticed that some threads appeared in the logs you provided.
If you click the Continue button several times, will the program trigger a breakpoint? If it can be hit, the issue should be caused by parallel threads. In addition, could you provide a minimal snippet that reproduces this issue and update it to the question?

Comment: @Alec-MSFT

Ive started hitting this problem recently as well. The code runs fine unless I attempt to place a break point.
Its a mature code base, creating a MRE would prove a lot of work, isn't there anything someone in this situation might do to figure out whats going wrong?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I am having the exact same issue and have been struggling to find a fix.

Comment: The same for me, did you find out how to resolve the problem? For me, it's only happening on Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing same problem and my workaround (not the fix) is debugging using the android device via USB cable instead of debugging via emulator where the issue exists. Definitely the Xamaring issue though.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it turned out it was because the breakpoint was on the main thread.

I moved the code I tried to break to to another thread and then it worked. It must have changed recently, so that you cannot break to code runnnig on main thread.